# Remove Transparent Light Gray Highlight On Surface 3 IE

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I'm making some changes to a web app that is displayed on a Surface 3 via IE.

Previously, everything was fine since the app was displayed via Chrome. But IT decided to switch to IE and things "broke."

I'm using Bootstrap.

The issue is when a carousel is used, the left/right arrow buttons, when tapped, display a light gray "highlight" over the element. I believe it's an `<a>` that's been styled as a button.

I've been working with the following but to no avail:

```
#carouselId1 a,
#carouselId1 a:hover,
#carouselId1 a:active,
#carouselId1 a:visited,
#carouselId2 a,
#carouselId2 a:hover,
#carouselId2 a:active,
#carouselId2 a:visited,
#carouselId5 a,
#carouselId5 a:hover,
#carouselId5 a:active,
#carouselId5 a:visited,
#carouselId6 a,
#carouselId6 a:hover,
#carouselId6 a:active,
#carouselId6 a:visited,
#carouselId1 a:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
    outline: none;
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
    -ms-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    background-image: none !important;
    filter: none !important; 
    progid:none !important;
}
```

The funny thing is that the gray highlighted element no longer displays on IE 11 on desktop. But remains on the Surface 3.

I'm developing on a MacBook Pro, using VisualStudio Code and Microsoft Document Connection. These tools can not be changed, fyi.

Attached is a picture I took of the gray highlighted element.

Thanks for your time in advance.

### #

UPDATE: I notice this only happens when touching/tapping. If I use trackpad on the Surface keyboard, and click on the button, there is no highlight.

Is this an IE thing or an OS thing?

### #

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just found out how to get rid of that light gray highlight/selection from the `html` element.

`touch-action: none;`

That was it!

After search on Google for a while, I came across this page:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj583807(v=vs.85).aspx

And it mentions the `touch-action` property.